# how get previous data row from sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, where-clause

for now i customize my query for get specific data, from that data i want to get previous row data

i tried this query but its getting error

```
SELECT  Data_date -(SELECT * FROM [x].[dbo].[JSON_SOURCE] WHERE Data_date <= (SELECT TOP(1) Data_Date
  FROM [x].[dbo].[JSON_SOURCE] 
  where ([Actual_cumulative] != null OR LTRIM(RTRIM([Actual_cumulative])) !='') 
  AND ([Early_Variance_monthly] != null OR LTRIM(RTRIM([Early_Variance_monthly])) !='' ) 
  AND ([Early_Variance_cumulative] != null OR LTRIM(RTRIM([Early_Variance_cumulative])) !='' ) 
  AND ([Late_Variance_monthly] != null OR LTRIM(RTRIM([Late_Variance_monthly])) !='' ) 
  AND ([Late_Variance_cumulative] != null OR LTRIM(RTRIM([Late_Variance_cumulative])) !='' ) 
  AND lower([Slug_Type]) IN('lg') ORDER BY Data_Date DESC) AND lower([Slug_Type]) IN('lg'))FROM [x].[dbo].[JSON_SOURCE]
```

this query is selecting the data i want, from this query result i want to take previous data is that posible?

```
SELECT * FROM [x].[dbo].[JSON_SOURCE] WHERE Data_date <= (SELECT TOP(1) Data_Date
  FROM [x].[dbo].[JSON_SOURCE] 
  where ([Actual_cumulative] != null OR LTRIM(RTRIM([Actual_cumulative])) !='') 
  AND ([Early_Variance_monthly] != null OR LTRIM(RTRIM([Early_Variance_monthly])) !='' ) 
  AND ([Early_Variance_cumulative] != null OR LTRIM(RTRIM([Early_Variance_cumulative])) !='' ) 
  AND ([Late_Variance_monthly] != null OR LTRIM(RTRIM([Late_Variance_monthly])) !='' ) 
  AND ([Late_Variance_cumulative] != null OR LTRIM(RTRIM([Late_Variance_cumulative])) !='' ) 
  AND lower([Slug_Type]) IN('lg') ORDER BY Data_Date DESC) AND lower([Slug_Type]) IN('lg')
```

Comment: Check lead and lag (also fetch next N rows only). You don't have sample data and excepted output so someone could help. It is cryptic to try to understand your intent from your code.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to join the table to itself and select a related row within the table to put alongside the original data.

To do this you can order and partition the query so along side each record you can place a number of related records which meet the WHERE clause and using the ORDER of the partition you then know which row to select.

I've introduced ISNULL to remove some of the complexity in your WHERE.

See how this works out, you may need to change some of the orders or >= <= operators.

```
Select *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_Number() over (partition by a.Id order by isnull(b.Data_Date,'1900-01-01') Desc) as RowOrder
    FROM [x].[dbo].[JSON_SOURCE] a
    left join [x].[dbo].[JSON_SOURCE] b
    ON a.Id != b.Id --Use whatever your Primary Key is to prevent selecting the same row as a secondary row.
    AND a.Data_date <= b.Data_date
    AND a.Slug_Type = b.Slug_Type
    WHERE
    LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(b.[Actual_cumulative],''))) !=''
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(b.[Early_Variance_monthly],''))) !='' 
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(b.[Early_Variance_cumulative],''))) !='' 
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(b.[Late_Variance_monthly],''))) !='' 
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(b.[Late_Variance_cumulative],''))) !='' 
    AND lower(a.[Slug_Type]) IN('lg')
) cte
WHERE cte.RowOrder = 1
```

Comment: I don't know if this query actually answers the question, but removing the complexity of the WHERE-clause is simple: `b.[Actual_cumulative] > ''`